# Macro to Loop Through All Worksheets in a Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a task to make the replacement of hyperlinks in 1000 files to a new server. I already have a working script for replacing hyperlinks, but it only works on the active page. Tell me how to make it go through all the pages in the book.

```
Sub changeLinks()

Const oldPrefix = "\\oldServer\common"
Const newPrefix = "\\NewServer\common"
Dim h As Hyperlink, oldLink As String, newLink As String

For Each h In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
    'this will change Address but not TextToDisplay
    oldLink = h.Address
    Debug.Print "Found link: " & oldLink
    If Left(oldLink, Len(oldPrefix)) = oldPrefix Then
            newLink = newPrefix & Right(h.Address, Len(h.Address) - Len(oldPrefix))


            h.Address = newLink
            Debug.Print "  Changed to " & h.Address
    End If
Next h

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Call your routine in a **loop**:

```
Sub ProcessAllSheets()
    Dim s As Worksheet
    For Each s In Sheets
        Call changeLinks(s.Name)
    Next s
End Sub
```

With these changes to your routine:

```
Sub changeLinks(s As String)

Const oldPrefix = "\\oldServer\common"
Const newPrefix = "\\NewServer\common"
Dim h As Hyperlink, oldLink As String, newLink As String

For Each h In Sheets(s).Hyperlinks
    'this will change Address but not TextToDisplay
    oldLink = h.Address
    Debug.Print "Found link: " & oldLink
    If Left(oldLink, Len(oldPrefix)) = oldPrefix Then
            newLink = newPrefix & Right(h.Address, Len(h.Address) - Len(oldPrefix))


            h.Address = newLink
            Debug.Print "  Changed to " & h.Address
    End If
Next h
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Throw a loop around your hyperlink loop to iterate through each sheet.

```
Sub changeLinks()
    Dim objSheet As Worksheet

    Const oldPrefix = "\\oldServer\common"
    Const newPrefix = "\\NewServer\common"
    Dim h As Hyperlink, oldLink As String, newLink As String

    For Each objSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        For Each h In objSheet.Hyperlinks
            'this will change Address but not TextToDisplay
            oldLink = h.Address

            Debug.Print "Found link: " & oldLink

            If Left(oldLink, Len(oldPrefix)) = oldPrefix Then
                newLink = newPrefix & Right(h.Address, Len(h.Address) - Len(oldPrefix))
                h.Address = newLink
                Debug.Print "  Changed to " & h.Address
            End If
        Next h
    Next
End Sub
```